# Текстовый поиск в файлах по нескольким вхождениям

Tags: поиск, текст, notepad++, totalcommander

Стоит задача найти в каталоге файлы содержащие сразу несколько слов.
Можно конечно написать что-то свое на C# или python, но есть ведь готовые инструменты.
Проблема в том что не работает поиск по двум или более словам, пробовал указать `&`, `&&`. Как я понял это потому что поиск с помощь регулярных выражений работает тольок в одной строке. Т.е. оба слова ищутся в одной строке.
Неужели нет способа найти слова между которыми несколько строк?

Comment: *Как я понял это потому что поиск с помощь регулярных выражений работает тольок в одной строке.* Ну это зависит от режима (флагов). Ничто не мешает воспринимать текст как одну длинную строку, содержащую в т.ч. и символы переноса строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя notepad++:

1. Заходим в Поиск->Найти в файлах;
2. В поле найти вбиваем `.*temp.*temp`, где `.*` это любые символы, а `temp` искомое слово для поиска;
3. Обязательно выбираем Режим поиска: Регулярное выражение и новые строки и жмакаем Найти всё, естественно указав при этом папку для поиска )